# How do you search through Vim's command history?

Tags: search, vim

I would like to have the following search in Vim too

```
(reverse-i-search)`':
```

Enter a word of your previous command, and you get the full command.

I know the chronological history tool in Vim

```
q:
```

However, it is not that useful as the fuzzy reverse search.

**How can you have a similar reverse search in Vim as in the terminal?**

Comment: @Masi: why it's not as useful? you can still search across that history so it makes it more powerful

Comment: the implementation for a reverse-i-search imitation is actually rather simple, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Enter the first letters of your previous command and push <Up> arrow (or Ctrl+p).

```
:set li<up>
:set lines=75
```

Don't forget to check history option and set it to big enough value

```
:set history=1000
```

Comment: If you have a Visor on Mac, try :set lines=48, instead. For some reason, the window expands too much with 75 lines.

Comment: 75 is just for example purpose but thanks for Visor. I didn't know about this one though I never need one. But I like it!

Comment: I use not a terminal Vim but MacVim.

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot better than the default history size, which I found out to be 20. No wonder my history had such a short-memory and I had to retype everything.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without arrow keys?

Comment: @Deiwin Ctrl+p (& Ctrl+n for next) as in bash command-line to call last command

Answer (score 179):

Type `q:` in the normal mode to open commands window. You can search/edit here using regular vim commands. You start in Normal mode. Press `Enter` to execute a command.

This approach lets you search across whole command not just beginning of line.

Comment: Now I know why I sometimes get command history instead of exiting a buffer or vim itself.

Comment: Any way to combine this with fzf?

Comment: @jchook there is a vim-fzf plugin that has :History: command that lets you fuzzy search across command history. No way to modify them before executing I'm afraid though.

Comment: @sumek: [`fzf.vim`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim)'s `:History:` does let you modify the command before executing it, with Ctrl + e.

Comment: @MatthiasBraun: That's avesome!!! Thanks a lot! :) Haven't noticed it before!

Answer (score 34):

Press **Ctrl+F** in command mode to open the command history window.  Then, you can use `/` , `?` , and other search commands.  Press Enter to execute a command from the history.

For more about the command history window, see [:h cmdwin](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html) .

Comment: Love it! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 13):

Here are the docs for [Vim's commandline history](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_20.html#20.4), also see this part of the docs on [Vim's commandline history](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#history) that covers the key bindings while in the history.  It looks like you can say `:foo` and then hit the up arrow to find the last command that started with foo.

Answer (score 10):

With FZF fuzzy search command: `:History:`

Source: https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for this as well (finally after wondering why it wasn't built-in for some time) and decided I couldn't resist whipping up an implementation, so here you go: https://github.com/goldfeld/ctrlr.vim

It should work just like the shell's--well there are still a couple basic things missing (like pressing ^R again to skip to next match), but all that I use is in this first release, and I plan to add the rest in the coming weeks as I get time.