# Reverse search completion of vim's command history without using direction keys

Tags: vim, autocomplete

Is there an option to auto-complete a currently typed command with one from the history, without using the direction keys?
This an extension to this question: [How do you search through vim's command history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741913/how-do-you-search-through-vims-command-history).

The answer was, after typing `:somecommand` to use the `<up>` key. I would think it is more vim-like not to have to lift the hand to go to the direction keys.

From `:help cmdline-completion`, I tried, `Ctrl-N`, `Ctrl-P`, `Ctrl-D`, `Ctrl-`L without success.
Here's maybe a related part of my vimrc.

```
set completeopt=menu,longest,preview
set showcmd     
set wildchar=<Tab> wildmenu wildmode=longest,list,full
set wildcharm=<C-Z>
```

I'm aware of the command line window invoked with `q:` or `:Ctrl-F` and the `Ctrl-N` and `Ctrl-P` to go through the history linearly after typing `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always map this to something. I once tried using

```
cnoremap <C-p> <Up>
```

, but this will disable completion cycling so you should better deduce something else (there is no way like `pumvisible()` to determine whether completion is active in command mode).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the "c"map. It seems that 
:cmap <C-k> <up>
--- and ---
:cmap <C-j> <down>
---works for me. I'll wait a bit, to see if there is other options.

Comment: @elmanuelito [Do never use `cmap`.](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html)

Comment: Yes, that was for testing, I did put a cnoremap for safety. Apart from that, do you think I'm missing much vim commands and functionality from using these two mappings? If not, and if nobody else shows us with an option without side effect, could you edit your answers with those mapping?

Comment: @elmanuelito I never used digraphs in command mode (since I have transliteration plugin to enter weird characters). And `<C-j>` is already covered by `<CR>`, so it should be fine.