# How can I see which my most used Vim commands are?

Tags: unix, vim, command-line, history

In bash I can [pipe the output](https://superuser.com/questions/250227/how-do-i-see-what-my-most-used-linux-command-are) of `history` to `awk`, `sort` and other utilities to get a nicely formatted view of my most used commands, and I was wondering if there was a way to achieve the same thing in Vim.

I'm mostly interested in normal mode commands, but it would be great to get a general overview including insert, visual and ex mode commands as well.

Comment: See http://www.drbunsen.org/vim-croquet/

Answer (score 0):

You can use suggestions posted at ([How do you search through vim's command history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741913/how-do-you-search-through-vims-command-history)) but I don't think there's the fully integrated reverse lookup option that you get with bash built in